# BlockChain: Private block chain technologies

Tags: private, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

As far as i understand, private block chains are built for an enterprise or a group of organizations.

While i am trying to explore, i came across few technologies like Hyperledger fabric, OpenChain, multiChain.

> 1. What are the technologies using which a private Block Chain can be built?
> 2. Is Hyperledger fabric a technology for private BlockChain? (As per this [link](https://magnr.com/blog/technology/private-vs-public-blockchains-bitcoin/), its public....hence confusing)

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of Blockchain could be private or public (open source), like all applications/projects.

Then, each implementation could be:

- Private (permissioned)
- Public (permisionless)

Bitcoin is a permisionless Blockcahin, anyone could take part on it.

Hyperledger Fabric is a project for creating permissioned Blockchains. In these Blockchains, there is someone who allows you to take part in the network. Once in the network, all the menbers share the same ledger. However, this Blockchains allow you to create your own Blockchain inside the network. So, some information could be accesible for only some members.

Then, you can use the Blockchain for whatever you want: to trace a product through the supply chain, to control a vote system...

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain networks are deployed in various domains including universal basic income programs, financial sector and even for humanitarian purposes. IBM saw the potential and launched its own “Blockchain as a service” by implementing a first of its kind enterprise ready blockchain.

IBM’s blockchain is based on The Linux Foundations' open source Hyperledger fabric. This fabric is like an operating system for data sharing networks, marketplaces, micro-currencies and decentralized digital communities. This further reduces cost and complexities involved in routine activities in various domains.

The applications and solutions developed under Hyperledger project follow a modular architecture where Hyperledger Fabric allows consensus and membership services to be plugged and play. Also, the component of smart contracts in Hyperledger host “chain code” that comprises of application logic system. Further, Hyperledger Fabric is a product of contributions by Digital Asset and IBM.

Blockchain technology at IBM aims at helping customers to create, deploy and manage blockchain network via cloud-based services. To bring blockchain technologies for commercial adoption, an open software development framework and approach is required which can ensure interoperability, longevity, transparency, and support.

For secure services to enterprise users, IBM has added another layer of security services and a highly auditable way of tracking activities.

At present, IBM isn’t just limited to enterprise mode of the blockchain; in 2015 IBM along with Samsung present a proof of concept for implementing blockchain with IoT, this was named as “Autonomous Decentralized Peer-to-Peer Telemetry”. This will be a revolutionary step for future of digital security and transparency.

You can learn more about IBM BlockChain and develop your own BlockChain @ https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ibm-blockchain-101-quick-start-guide-for-developers-bluemix-trs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The private block chain is a bit different than what we learn from Bitcoin, it has its own way of operating. For example, hyper ledger project from Linux and IBM focus on the building BaaS(BlockChain as a service). Where you can build e-e application using IBM Bluemix tool for your intranet work. It may have N number of application. The private blockchain is essential to those who want to build blockchain on top of their existing product.IBM Blockchain solution using their hyper ledger fabric enabling you to focus on powerful features of Blockchain for business https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain